# Render a seperate html file and place inside an ext js panel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am new to ext js, I have a separate index.html file that contains like a gallery of pictures how can I call that html and place it inside the panel or window.

```
var GalleryWindow = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
            iconCls: Function.Window.Icon,
            title: Function.Window.Text,
            constrainHeader: true,
            closeAction: 'hide',
            collapsible: false,
            forceLayout: true,
            maximizable: true,
            minimizable: true,
            resizable: true,
            closable: true,
            layout: 'fit',
            height: '70%',
            width: '60%',
            modal: true
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `iframe` tag inside of ExtJS component using [`autoEl`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-autoEl) config.

**AutoEl**  tag name or [DomHelper](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.DomHelper) spec used to create the [Element](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-getEl) which will encapsulate this Component.

You do not normally need to specify this. For the base classes [Ext.Component](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.Component) and [Ext.container.Container](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.container.Container), this defaults to `div`. The more complex Sencha classes use a more complex DOM structure specified by their own [renderTpls](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-renderTpl).

This is intended to allow the developer to create application-specific utility Components encapsulated by different DOM elements. Example usage:

```
{
    xtype: 'component',
    autoEl: {
        tag: 'iframe',
        src: 'http://www.example.com/example.html'
    }
}
```

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2d01)**, I have created a demo using same as above I have mentioned. I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            title: 'Open other index file inside of window',
            height: 500,
            width: 500,
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [{
                xtype: "component",
                autoEl: {
                    tag: "iframe",
                    src: "res/example.html"
                }
            }]
        }).show();
    }
});
```

**CODE SNIPPET for example.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Button Styles</h2>
        <button type="button" class="btn">Basic</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>
        <br>

        <h2>Nesting Button Groups & Dropdown Menus</h2>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Apple</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Samsung</button>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Sony <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Tablet</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Smartphone</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>

        <h2>Bootstrap Alerts</h2>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.
        </div>

        <div class="alert alert-info">
            <strong>Info!</strong> Indicates a neutral informative change or action.
        </div>

        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <strong>Warning!</strong> Indicates a warning that might need attention.
        </div>

        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Danger!</strong> Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action.
        </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @narendrajadvah Hello there :) This is a good implementation but i've an additional question; Can I adapt my viewmodel to work with this `iframe`? i.e.: I want to use `bind` as this way in HTML; `<b>Phone</b>: {currRec.phone}`

Comment: one more question; unfortunately I can not show my `html` file exist in project while when production build runs file been lost:
`http://localhost:8282/app/my/foo/dir/ForBar.html 404 (File not found)`